# Как создать java web start приложение?

Tags: javaws, java

Как создать java web start приложение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно для получения результата хватает пройти квест, начиная [отсюда](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html)
Если же интересует что-то более конкретное, то задавайте более конкретный вопрос